# Making commands into subfolders

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so I can add my commands into subfolders to organize them better but still have the commands work. I have tried to figure out how to change my code to be that way but my code looks completely different than everyone else's that I'm a little stuck.

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const folders = fs.readdirSync('./commands'); // read the directory of folders

for (var folder of folders) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`); // for each folder, read the files in the folder
    for (var file of files) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`); // for each file, set the command
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I tried this and upon starting up the bot I received an error: Cannot find module './commands/hug.js'. I moved my hug.js command into a subfolder under "commands"

Comment: Oh oops. I made a mistake. I have fixed it.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't catch that myself but the update code works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help